# how to draw a line on top of a panel. use "screen space overlay " canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried to use the LineRenderer component, but nothing works, it is always displayed behind the Canvas and panel.
Help me!!

Comment: You can use thin Image objects as your line and you can rotate/position them as you wish. Alternatively, [you can create your own UI mesh by extending from Graphic/MaskableGraphic](https://youtu.be/UFo-gAkXLa4?t=799).

Comment: I change z position but is not work

Comment: You can't use LineRenderer on Screen Space-Overlay canvas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code from the link:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/189371
I slightly modified it. And it perfectly worked for me in screen space-overlay canvas.
You can also see my (modified) code below:

```
private void createALine(Vector2 objpositionA, Vector2 objpositionB)
{        
    GameObject angleBar = new GameObject("dotConnection", typeof(Image));
    angleBar.transform.SetParent(Container, false);
    angleBar.GetComponent<Image>().color = clr;
    
    /**/
    /*calculate angle*/
    Vector2 diference = objpositionA - objpositionB;
    float sign = (objpositionA.y < objpositionB.y) ? -1.0f : 1.0f;
    float angle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.right, diference) * sign;
    angleBar.transform.Rotate(0, 0, angle);
    /**/
    /*calculate length of bar*/
    float height = 5;
    float width = Vector2.Distance(objpositionB, objpositionA);
   
    /*calculate midpoint position*/
    float newposX = objpositionB.x + (objpositionA.x - objpositionB.x) / 2;
    float newposY = objpositionB.y + (objpositionA.y - objpositionB.y) / 2;
    RectTransform rectTransform = angleBar.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
    rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);
    rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(newposX, newposY, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use the default line renderer on UI. You can use the [UILineRenderer](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/UILineRenderer) from unity ui extensions repository

Comment: UILineRenderer is not show in my unity (pls help me)

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem Just create a UI line renderer object by right clicking the hierarchy, then selecting UI>Extensions>Primitives>UI Line Renderer. Then create 2 or more points in the UI line renderer's "Points" field in the editor. If you can't do it, create a new question in stackoverflow. Also please close this question if you got your answer

Comment: search for uiLinerender extension and install it